# Is it okay to lift weights daily?

Tags: weightlifting, weight-loss, crunches

I used to live a sedentary life behind the desk. This year, I decided to change my lifestyle. 
 
I'm 6ft; I started with 236lbs on January 1st and currently weigh about 215lbs.

 
What I do is simple: do 30 minutes of Insanity every morning and in the evening, do an hour (or thereabout) of P90X. Or just an hour of regular weightlifting (bars, dumbbells, crunches, etc); I'm not really following any specific routine.

 
Also, I decided to move my body as much as possible. So, I use the stairs a lot, sit upright in chairs, do crunches in chairs, and try standing on one leg at every chance I get.

 
Because my work is about an hour drive and there's usually traffic (in the mornings and evenings), I carry a 35lbs dumbbell with me, and when in traffic, I lift it or do crunches. I do this every workweek day. ***I mainly do this as a way to bypass the boredom associated with staying in traffic***.

 
I currently don't feel any pain anywhere (I feel great, in fact); however, I want to know if I'm in anyway creating a problem in my body that might come bite me later. 
 
Also, since muscles need time to relax and heal, does all these daily weightlifting negatively impact my body in anyway? 

 
Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying to picture how to do crunches and lifting behind the wheel of a car.

Comment: @MatthewJamesBriggs Lol.....I was desperate. Throwing everything at the weight. I don't do that anymore :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your muscles need recovery time.  However, that varies from person to person.  Person A may only be able to lift 3x a week, while Person B can lift everyday.  You should probably incorporate 2 days a week with just some light lifting (or muscle groups you don't target) and some cardio, then lift the other days.

You probably shouldn't lift the same muscle groups on back-to-back days either.  For instance, if you are hitting triceps/chest, you shouldn't target those groups the next day.  I like to do triceps/chest, biceps/back, rest day, traps/shoulders, legs/core, rest day, then repeat.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Okay...but the traffic time weightlifting can only target specific muscles; again, it's goal is simply to bypass the traffic boredom *(doing something just for the sake)*. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that in addition to regulating the muscle groups accordingly you make sure you warm up properly and stretch too, very important so you do not get hurt.

Otherwise lifting weights is good for you.

Have a look at [muscleandfitness.com](http://muscleandfitness.com) for some good workouts and do them carefully and safely.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I've had great success lifting every day. However you need to give your body time to adapt. You can't start lifting as hard as you can every day, you will only hurt yourself. Start with 4 days then slowly add another day as you get used to the stress.

Be mindful that your diet and sleeping are on point, they become much more important when you exert yourself that often.

Comment: Thanks....I've changed my diet and it's working fine. Sleep though, isn't looking good so far (probably about 3-5 hrs a night, unless on weekends).

Comment: 3-5hrs isn't nearly enough. If you don't rest enough your cortisol levels will rise, and that's a both long term health risk and a short term impediment to recovery. If you're going to be taking your training this seriously you will have to make sacrifices. And if you can't make those sacrifices then something else has to give, either your mind and body or the frequency of your training.

Comment: Thanks.....I'll see what I can do; I don't want to reduce the intensity though (as my body's really changing nicely); at the moment, life just makes finding more sleep time elusive.